# Upgrading Spring boot to 2.5.14 from 2.4.13

Tags: spring-boot, version, upgrade, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing issue with elasticsearch while upgrading spring boot version.

Elastic search versions are as follows :

```
o.s.d.e.support.VersionInfo.logVersions - Version Spring Data Elasticsearch: 4.2.11
o.s.d.e.support.VersionInfo.logVersions - Version Elasticsearch Client in build: 7.12.1
o.s.d.e.support.VersionInfo.logVersions - Version Elasticsearch Client used: 7.12.1
```

Cause :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Request execution cancelled
```

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.2 is out of maintenance since April 2022. Spring Boot 2.5 since May 2022. You should upgrade to current versions

Answer (score 0):

Using specific version '4.0.0.RELEASE' of spring data elasticsearch made the app start for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```